# Amazon Web Services(AWS) Lambda Canonicalization Error for Turkish Language

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, canonicalization

I am facing canonicalization problem while using aws-android-sdk-lambda from Android phone.While function call it somehow uses phone's language, btw it is Turkish, so I get SigningKeyDoesntMatchException. If I change phone language to English, it reaches aws correctly. As you can see "x-amz-ä±nvocation-type" string is corrupted, it should be like "x-amz-invocation-type".

As a solution I tried to change phone language to English before function call, but I need a permanent solution.It drives me crazy.
Thank you for your time.

```
﹕ AWS Lambda Function Error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/2015-03-31/functions/hello-world/invocations
host:lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20160212T202327Z
x-amz-security-token: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
x-amz-target:AWSLambda.Invoke
x-amz-ä±nvocation-type:
host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target;x-amz-ä±nvocation-type
be9ba4e61f0079a705bfbf17c9e09abe670f22e18d56f8e83f1d7487101fe072'
The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20160212T202327Z
20160212/us-east-1/lambda/aws4_request
f5f0f3589e8c8e2acc91246da3c979fdb5e8e823983c5ffe86dccbab9e228c11'
(Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidSignatureException; Request ID: 7a7d9b57-d1c6-11e5-9e3b-a59637a66ac7)
```

Comment: Would you please open an issue on Github https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android? We'll address it ASAP.

Comment: Thank you, issue created : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/96

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in v2.2.13 release. Please update the SDK at https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/. Check out what is changed in the [change log](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Thank you, you are great! @Yangfan